# How to get input from a file using fscanf ignoring commas?

Tags: c, input, formatting, scanf

So, i got this file with a bunch of text. I need to use fscanf to get word by word and ignore the commas. So `this,` should be read as `this`.

I tried

```
fscanf(file,"[^,]",string);
```

but it stops at the word with a comma.

How can I do this?

I can only use fscanf to ignore the comma, no additional logic

Comment: `fscanf(file,"%[^,],",string);`

Answer (score 3):

This is a more sturdy version.  It accepts any combination of white space and commas as word separators:

Assuming `char string[100];`

```
for (;;) {
    /* skip any spaces and an optional comma */
    fscanf(file, " ,");
    if (fscanf(file," %99[^, \t\n\f\r\v]", string) == 1) {
        /* handle string value read from file */
    }
    if (feof(file))
        break;
}
```

With this format string, `fscanf` will skip white space and an optional comma, read the next word, stopping at `','` or on a white space character, handles the `string` if successfully read, and continues until the end of `file`.

`fscanf` will return `1` if `string` was read, otherwise it will not even modify `string`.  This can happen if the stream `file` is at end of file before the call, or if there are multiple commas in a row. These will be parsed in successive iterations until there is an actual word to read.

Comment: As OP said "I can only use `fscanf`", could replace the needed separate `getc(file)` with `fscanf(file, "%c")`.

Comment: The `fscanf(file, "%*c");` should be separated from `fscanf(file," %99[^, ]%*c",string)`.  If input begins with`','`, then `string` is left uninitialized and `','` remains in `file`.    Better to `string[0] = 0; if fscanf(file,"%99[^, ]",string) ...; fscanf(file,"%*c")` - closer to your original answer.

Comment: If `file` begins with `','`, `fscanf` fails in both cases.  The same happens if there is more than 1 comma after a word with or without intervening spaces.  `fscanf` is so inappropriate for parsing input ;-).  I'll edit the post for a more sturdy solution.

Comment: The difference when file begins with `','`, is that `fscanf(file," %99[^, ]%*c",string)` does not consume the `','`, yet `fscanf(file,"%99[^, ]",string); fscanf(file,"%*c")` does.  Hence the advantage with your 1st approach and the present one with a separate `fscanf()` call.  IAC, I agree `fscanf()` is not so inappropriate for parsing.

Comment: @chux: you mean to say *I agree `fscanf()` is not so* appropriate *for parsing*?

Comment: Yes - meant to say "`fscanf()` is not so appropriate for parsing."  Very minor: One more standard white-space `'\v'`.